# use-package with builtin mode, such as display-time-mode

Tags: init-file, use-package, error, aquamacs

I'm trying to use the `use-package` method of organizing my `Preferences.el` file in Aquamacs.  When I try to use `use-package display-time-mode`, I get the following error message.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "display-time-mode")
  require(display-time-mode nil nil)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/hdeyoung/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1110
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/hdeyoung/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el" "/Users/hdeyoung/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el" t nil)
  load("~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences" t)
  (let ((user-init-file file)) (load user-init-file t))
  (lambda (file) (let ((user-init-file file)) (load user-init-file t)))("~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences")
  mapc((lambda (file) (let ((user-init-file file)) (load user-init-file t))) ("/Library/Preferences/Emacs/Preferences" "/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences" "~/Library/Preferences/Emacs/Preferences" "~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences"))
  (if init-file-debug (mapc (function (lambda (file) (let ((user-init-file file)) (load user-init-file t)))) aquamacs-preference-files) (mapc (function (lambda (file) (let ((user-init-file file)) (condition-case error (load user-init-file t) (error (let ... ... ... ... ...)))))) aquamacs-preference-files))
  (if (equal init-file-user nil) nil (condition-case nil (load custom-file) (error (message "Loading `custom-file' failed."))) (if init-file-debug (mapc (function (lambda (file) (let ((user-init-file file)) (load user-init-file t)))) aquamacs-preference-files) (mapc (function (lambda (file) (let ((user-init-file file)) (condition-case error (load user-init-file t) (error ...))))) aquamacs-preference-files)) (aquamacs-activate-features-new-in-this-version))
  aquamacs-load-preferences()
  #[0 "\205\274 \305=\203\306\307Q\202? \310=\204\306\311Q\202?\312\306\313\314#\203*\315\202?\312\306\313\316#\203>\317\320\321!D\nB\322\202?\315\323\324\323\211#\210\325\326!\203P\326 \210\323=\203n\327\330\331\306\332Q!\"\324\323\211#\210\323=\203m\210\203\260\333!\334\232\203\260\335!\211\336P\337!\203\212\211\202\225\337!\203\224\202\225\313\262\203\256\340\"\203\254\341\342#\210\343\344!\210\266\f?\205\272\324\345\323\211#\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" initialization format-message "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'" "~/_emacs" t load fboundp aquamacs-load-preferences expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

What am I doing wrong?
For reference, here is my `Preferences.el` file.

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu"   . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))

(package-initialize)
(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(eval-and-compile
  (setq use-package-always-ensure t
        use-package-expand-minimally t))

(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)

(use-package display-time-mode
  :ensure nil
  :custom
    (display-time-default-load-average nil))
```

Comment: What is the value of `load-path` (`C-h v load-path` and add it to the question)? Do `M-x locate-library RET time` - what does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `display-time-mode` is not a package; it's a minor mode defined in the built-in package `time` (time.el). The first argument to `use-package` must be a package. [*More accurately this argument must be a feature; see below for a more detailed explanation.*]

The following code loads the `time` package, enables `display-time-mode`, and sets `display-time-default-load-average` to nil:

```
(use-package time
  :ensure nil
  :config
  (display-time-mode 1)
  :custom
  (display-time-default-load-average nil))
```

---

*Information about features:*

As pointed out by @shynur, `use-package` - like `require` - actually takes a *feature* as its first argument. A feature is a symbol that Emacs uses to represent ["a collection of functions, variables, etc"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html). Packages define a feature name using `provide`. By convention, the feature name is the same name as the name of the file (minus the file extension).

When `use-package` (or `require`) is called on a symbol that does not appear in the feature namespace, Emacs will look through the `load-path` to try to find a .el or .elc file that matches the provided symbol. If it does, it will load that package (which will then call the `provide` function to add the feature into the feature-namespace).

The benefit of using features is that it allows a package to only be loaded once even if it is required many times. Once a feature has been provided, if the corresponding package is loaded again by `require` or `use-package` then its source code will not run again. Whereas every time the function `load` is used the code will run. An example of where this is helpful is if many packages all use the same library. If they all use `require`, then the package will only need to be loaded once.

Comment: “*The first argument to use-package must be a \_package\_.*” — minor mistake. It is a feature symbol.

Comment: @shynur Thank you for that correction. I added some text below my original answer to provide information about how features are used by require and use-package.